# mp4 videos not supported in multiple line of text column with enhanced rich text

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, video, multiple-lines-of-text

I have created a list column of type multiple line of text column with enhanced rich text.

I inserted mp4 video of size 1 MB in an item in this column. This Is the video I am using - http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

When I tried to play the video in list, it shows me message that 'Media failed to load. The file is in a format that is not recognized.'

I am storing this video in an asset library. When I try to play video from Asset Library itself, it shows the same message.

Comment: Can you share screen shot of that????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found from search that this happens if your mp4 file is using the H.264 video codec with either MP3 or AAC audio. I would suggest try to either try another type of file for testing purposes, just to confirm the codec is the issue or not!

Comment: It was problem with the file itself. Tried another file and it worked. Thanks..!!